# Probability of monochromatic poker hands

Tags: probability, poker

I play poker occasionally and have been thinking about the probability to make an all-red (diamond, heart) or all-black (club, spade) hand – a *monochromatic hand*. What I have come up with seems like the correct answer and I would like to get confirmation or correction.

According to Wikipedia the probability of hitting a flush is $508:1$. So I would think that it is as simple as $254:1$, since in a regular flush you can only use one suit but here you can use two.

I am pretty sure there is something I am missing, since if you have $4$ hearts you make a flush with another heart, but a monochromatic with a diamond.

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom{26}5$ all-red hands and the same number of all-black hands. There are $\binom{52}5$ hands overall. The probability of drawing
a monochrome hand is
$$2\frac{\binom{26}5}{\binom{52}5}\approx0.0462.$$

Comment: That translates to 4.62% correct? So that puts it between Two Pairs and Three of a Kind. Seems legit.
How come I get a different result when I use this method: 26 / 52 * 13 / 51 * 12 / 50 * 11 / 49 * 10 / 48 = 0.00143

Comment: No, that does not seem right. It should be 26 / 52 * 25 / 51 * 24 / 50 * 23 / 49 * 22 / 48 = 0.02531

Comment: How about $(25/51)(24/50)(23/49)(22/48)$?

Comment: I get a different number  0.0506202481